# Power BI - Incremental Refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

My data source is Blob storage which is around 270MB of data and is taking around 4.5 hours to refresh. So encountered  120 minute timeout issue on power bi service. Therefore gave a try at setting incremental refresh.

I don't think I have premium license as it shows 10GB storage at the top right hand corner on my Power bi Service. Does this mean that I wont be able to set the incremental refresh?

But I gave a try as below:

I manually created **RangeStart** and **RangeEnd** parameters in the manage parameters as below (as there were no default ones), but not sure about the "Current value" field (See below)? So I left it blank and sorted the date/time column according to these parameters 
[image]

And the next step, while enabling the incremental refresh, the button has been greyed out as below:
[image]

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  Incremental refresh is a PBI Premium preview feature only.